# How can I call this kind of function in Hibernate?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, plsql

Well, I have got a pl/sql function with next structure:

```
function  Proc(SessionID SomeConst.TSessionID default null) return sys_refcursor is
  rc sys_refcursor
```

I don't have any experience with pl/sql, but now I have to call this somehow. I know that this kind of procedure:

```
procedure LogOn(UserName in varchar2, Password in varchar2, SessionID out varchar2)
```

must be called like this:

```
CallableStatement callableStatement = sessionFactory
                .getCurrentSession().connection()
                .prepareCall("call PREQUEST.LOGON(?,?,?)");
        callableStatement.setString(1, userName);
        callableStatement.setString(2, password);
        callableStatement.registerOutParameter(3, OracleTypes.VARCHAR);
        callableStatement.execute();
        return callableStatement.getString(3);
```

But `Proc` has no `out` parameter. What do?

**UPD:**

```
System.out.println(sessionFactory
                        .getCurrentSession()
                        .createSQLQuery(
                                "select Proc(:sessionId) from dual")
                        .setString("sessionId", sessionId).list().size());
```

I tried this, but console says:

> org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: -10

Answer (score 1):

```
Query query=session.createSQLQuery("select Proc('"+param+"') from dual");
List<MappedBean> result=query.list();
```

Since your function returns `sys_refcursor`, get a bean say `MappedBean` which would hold the data returned from function.

Comment: MappedBean must be a Hibernate entity?

Comment: Yes a Hibernate entity.

Comment: I added some details. Pls look.

Comment: You cannot call a procedure like a function in hibernate. Either use callable statement or named queries, if you use named query then procedure must have first out parameter and it should be sys_refcursor of oracle.